# Does running time on an executable significantly increase run time

Tags: time

Does running `time` on a shell command noticeably increase the runtime of the command itself?  After all, since it distinguishes between time spent in user space and time spent waiting for system calls doesn't there have to be a lot of overhead to monitor those separate events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, using the `time` command does not noticeably increase the runtime of the command itself. The `time` command gets much of its information from the `times()` system call; the values come from the kernel which collects the information whether or not `times()` is called or not.  See `man 2 times` for more information on the `times()` system call.

Comment: The same information is used for the ps output for processes, to enforce the ulimit for cpu time, as input for OOM decisions, by System Monitor, and probably for much else.

Comment: That is very cool!  Thanks!